# Python - Extract text that starts with a particular sub-string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am working on extracting certain text from emails using Python Regex

I have tried below:

```
import re

email = """Hi John,

I am emailing regarding REQ-12345 and REQ-66442.

Many Thanks,

Jane"""


re.findall(r'(?=REQ-)',email)
```

Expected Output: `['REQ-12345', 'REQ-66442']`

Actual Output: `['', '']`

I have also tried multiple different things which aren't giving the right results.

How do I achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re

email = """Hi John,

I am emailing regarding REQ-12345 and REQ-66442.

Many Thanks,

Jane"""


re.findall(r'(REQ-\d+)',email)
```

```
['REQ-12345', 'REQ-66442']
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Working Exactly. :)

Comment: @excelman Great, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem, otherwise, it will keep coming up in the open question list.

Answer (score 1):

Expected Output: `['REQ-12345', 'REQ-66442']`

Do not use zero-length assertion then (it is useful for grabing text after or before something without getting that thing), if `REQ-` is always followed by 1 or more digits (`0123456789`) following should suffice

```
import re
text = "I am emailing regarding REQ-12345 and REQ-66442."
print(re.findall(r'REQ-[0-9]+',text))
```

output

```
['REQ-12345', 'REQ-66442']
```